# Table-like display for a calculator

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a calculator on a page.  Since it is not tabular data I should not use a table to style it. I've read around about various layouts and am unsuccessful so far and would like to ask for guidance. Please find the validated XHTML at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sbel/dqYsS/2/) in which I made a table with one row and three columns demonstrating what I'm getting at.  jsfiddle doesn't display it correctly so you would need to paste it locally. I would appreciate if you can advise.

Comment: Just turn off normalised CSS like so: http://jsfiddle.net/dqYsS/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the best (non-table) markup you can think of (not just `<div>`), but apply table-based styling:
[`display: table | table-row-group | table-row |  table-cell`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display)

Comment: At the risk of sounding not good I will say that reading W3C Recommendation is difficult for me.